# Using ng-model within a directive

Tags: angularjs

I've got a custom defined directive in angularjs.  Basically what I want to happen is the user will pick a value from a select box and that will append a value to an array.  This causes my custom directive to be invoked and render a new element on the screen.  I want the text field that the directive generates to bind to the controller's attribute.

Html

```html
<device-list ng-repeat="device in devices" key="device.key" display-name="device.display_name" bind-prefix="descriptions"></device-list>
```

Directive

```js
angular.module('device_list_tag', []).
  directive('deviceList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '?ngModel',
      scope: {
        devices: '=',
        key: '=',
        displayName: '=',
        bindPrefix: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var deviceListElement = $(element)
        var containerDiv = $('<div>')
          .addClass('row')


        var labelTag = $('<label>').text(scope.displayName)
          .addClass('span1')

        var bindField = attrs.bindPrefix+'.'+scope.key

        var textField = $('<input>')
          .addClass('span3')
          .attr('ng-model', bindField)

        containerDiv.append(labelTag)
        containerDiv.append(textField)

        deviceListElement.append(containerDiv)
      }
    }
  })
```

Controller

```js
function DevicesCtrl($scope) {
  descriptions = {}
}
```

It appears as though as ng-model is local to the directive's scope, how do I make it apply to the parent?  If I have a bunch of text fields on the page like

```html
<input ng-model="descriptions.test"/>
```

It works works except with the fields generated by the select box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  It involved passing in my parent attribute as '=' (suggested by Tosh).  I also had to make a call to $compile to make it recognize the ng-model directive.  Here's the full code, I'm sure there's a way to do this cleaner but I'm just glad to have it working.

```js
angular.module('device_list_tag', []).
  directive('deviceList', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        devices: '=',
        key: '=',
        displayName: '=',
        bindAttr: '=' // added
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        console.log(scope)

        var deviceListElement = $(element)
        var containerDiv = $('<div>')
          .addClass('row')


        var labelTag = $('<label>').text(scope.displayName)
          .addClass('span1')

        var bindField = 'bindAttr.'+scope.key

        var textField = $('<input>')
          .addClass('span3')
          .attr('ng-model', bindField)

        $compile(textField)(scope) // added

        containerDiv.append(labelTag)
        containerDiv.append(textField)

        deviceListElement.append(containerDiv)
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a template attribute in the directive and bind you object as you normally would? E.g.: template: '<input ng-model="bindAttr" />...' Isn't this what the template is for or did I got u wrong? Like the example on the bottom of the page: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: The problem is I don't know the name of the attribute I'm going to be binding to from within the directive.  I tried using a template but the problem I ran into was how to get {{some.random.attribute}} to work.

Comment: I would bind a fixed variable and just update the variable to the value of some.random.attribute ones I figured out what that is. You could for example set up a function called getSomeRandomAttr(key) which is connected to your parents scope or calls a server. Then you just need to update fixed variable after calling the function.

Comment: Could you please post the html portion of the working `<device-list..` directive for us to know.

Comment: I believe the final html is: `<device-list ng-repeat="device in devices" key="device.key" display-name="device.display_name" bind-attr="descriptions"></device-list>`

Answer (score 2):

May be you can add `bindField: '='` in your scope directive definition.
And use this variable to connect to the parent scope.

Comment: I'm playing around with that now, but haven't been able to figure out how to "bind" the variable to the text field.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for,

1) Keep the parent scope array updated, while we edit the isolate scope form elements. If yes, i have replicated a similar scenario in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W7YrZ/2/.

Summary of what i was trying to do.

1) Assign a attribute `umbilical` in the `ng-repeat` with the current item of the iteration.

2) Then im evaluating this attribute inside the linking function in the context of the parent scope, which gives a reference(pointer) to one of the array object in the parent scope array here `profiles`.

3)Then as @Mark Rajcok says "primitives are copied by value, while objects are copied by reference". I'm binding that object got through step 2 to the text boxes in the template string.

Comment: This worked fantastic for me, and was the key I was missing (in my case I was writing a date range directive and was struggling to get the ng-model to map to a start and end range variable.

Answer (score -3):

for reasons of cleanliness of jQuery code in angular and for validation javascript, just replace the selector `$` in `angular.element`

```
$('<input>').addClass('span3')
```

must be written

```
angular.element('<input>').addClass('span3')
```