# Using controller-scoped data in a directive's jqlite-generated html

Tags: html, scope, angularjs, directive

This question is similiar to them one asked in [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197862/mike)'s post [Using ng-model within a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717897/using-ng-model-within-a-directive).

I am writing a page which is small spreadsheet that displays calculated output based on user input fields.  Using a directive, I'm making custom tags like this:

```
<wbcalc item="var1" title="Variable 1" type="input"></wbcalc>
<wbcalc item="var2" title="Variable 2" type="input"></wbcalc>
<wbcalc item="calc" title="Calculation" type="calc"></wbcalc>
```

The 'item' field references scoped data in my controller:

```
$scope.var1 = '5';  // pre-entered input
$scope.var2 = '10'; // pre-entered input
$scope.calc = function() {
    return parseInt($scope.var1) + parseInt($scope.var2);
};
```

And the 'type' field is used in the directive's logic to know whether to treat the item as a string or a function.

Here's a fiddle for this:  http://jsfiddle.net/gregsandell/PTkms/3/  I can get the output elements to work with the astonishing line of code:

```
html.append(angular.element("<span>")
    .html(scope.$eval(attrs.item + "()"))
);
```

...and I'm using this to get my inputs connected to my scoped controller data (I got this from [Mike's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717897/using-ng-model-within-a-directive):

```
var input = angular.element("<input>").attr("ng-model", attrs.item);
$compile(input)(scope);
html.append(input);
```

...while it does put the values in the fields, they aren't bound to the calculation, as you can see by changing inputs in my fiddle.

Is there a better and/or more intuitive way to link my controller-scoped data to the jqlite-generated html in my directive?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this, I think you can simplify the process a fair bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/PTkms/4/

```
angular.module('calculator', []).directive('wbcalc', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><div class="span2">{{title}}</div><input ng-model="item"></div>',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            item: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Don't need to do this.
        }
    }
});
function calcCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.var1 = '5';
    $scope.var2 = '10';

    $scope.calc = function() {
        // Yes, this is a very simple calculation which could
        // have been handled in the html with {{0 + var1 + var2}}.
        // But in the real app the calculations will be more
        // complicated formulae that don't belong in the html.
        return parseInt($scope.var1) + parseInt($scope.var2);
    };
}
```

I know you said you like jQuery - but to make best use of Angular you need to think in an Angular way - use bindings, don't manipulate the DOM directly etc.

For this example, it would be helpful to read up on the isolated scope bindings used - '@' and '=', see:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't know about the isolated scope bindings and will read up on that.  I notice that you chose to do the html as a string:

     template: '<div><div class="span2">{{title}}</div><input ng-model="item"></div>'

I had also found (earlier) that such strings seem to work better than the structured jqLite in my fiddle.  It seems like the structured approach make less error-prone code.  Why is it frowned upon in the angularjs world?

Comment: In a very short explanation - Angular has a concept called 'compiling' which basically takes your templates and links the binding etc - you need to do this to get things like two-way binding working. By convention this expects you to point to a template or templateUrl - although you can build marking structurally, you have to jump through hoops to do so. It takes a while to change from jQuery thinking but once you do it's worth it!